# Run a event click after sucessful reload of a bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events, bootstrap-table

I have this function, where I have a **ajax call** and in the success function, i have refresh the bootstrap table, now after the refresh i have a trigger **command** which i want to happen only when the refresh is done, how to do that,

```
success: function (result) {
console.log(result);
$('#overlay').hide();
 swal({
       title: result['msg'],
       // text: result['text'],
       type: result['type'],
       showConfirmButton: true
 });
 $('#prospect_table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
     element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click')
 }
```

the last event click happens at its specific time but I want to run that command only when the refresh is done,ie `status=200`

Thanks!

I have tried:

```
var evnCilck = element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click'); // Or any other click function
$('#prospect_table').bootstrapTable('refresh', function(e){
    evnCilck();
});
```

and

```
$('#prospect_table').bootstrapTable('refresh', function() {
element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

No help from this.

Comment: Don't double post. Remove this post or the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58654598/2813224)

Comment: I haven't double posted anything, and the link is broken anyway ?

Comment: If you want to trigger your event after table body rendered then you should use the event "onPostBody".

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but yes it is helpful

Comment: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onloadsuccess

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$('#prospect_table').bootstrapTable('refresh', function() {
element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: First thing, this is syntactically wrong as a function should be there for a definition, and second this i tried, `$('#prospect_table').bootstrapTable('refresh', function() {
element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click');
});` , but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Along with triggering an refresh event You also need to bind refresh eventlistener to the table like this :

```
var $table = $('#table');
$table.on('refresh.bs.table',function(){
 // do your stuff here  
   element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by this way -

```
var evnCilck = element.parent('div').parent('div').parent('td').parent('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first').find('a').trigger('click'); // Or any other click function
$('#prospect_table').bootstrapTable('refresh', function(e){
    evnCilck();
});
```

Comment: There is no difference in your answer and Saqlain's answer, and its not working either